# Self-referential find in controller count relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, find, self-reference

I'm having real trouble pulling out a set of records that are self-referentially related to a user in order to show these on a user's 'show' page.

Here's the idea:

Users (`current_user`) rate the compatibility between two other users (`user_a` and `user_b`). They can rate compatibility either positively or negatively: rating two users "compatible" creates a `positive_connection` between user_a and user_b, and rating them "incompatible" creates a `negative_connection`. So there are models for positive_connection, negative_connection and user.

Now I need to display only users that are `overall_positively_connected_to(@user)` (i.e. where `positive_connections_to(@user).count > negative_connections_to(@user).count)`.

This is where I've got to, but I can't get any further:

User model:

```
  def overall_positive_connected_to(user)
      positive_connections_to(user).count > negative_connections_to(user).count
  end


  def positive_connections_to(user)
      positive_connections.where("user_b_id = ?", user)
  end     

  def negative_connections_to(user) 
      negative_connections.where("user_b_id = ?", user)
  end
```

Controller

```
@user.user_bs.each do |user_b|
  if user_b.overall_pos_connected_to(@user)
    @compatibles = user_b
  end
end
```

The code in the controller is clearly wrong, but how should I go about doing this? I'm completely new to rails (and sql), so may have done something naive.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So am I right in saying you have 3 models

- User (id, name)
- PositiveConnection (user_a_id, user_b_id)
- NegativeConnection (user_a_id, user_b_id)

Or something of that sort.

I think you just want 2 models
and for convenience I'm going to rename the relations as "from_user" and "to_user"

- User (id, name)
- Connection (value:integer, from_user_id, to_user_id)

Where value is -1 for a negative
and +1 for a positive.

Now we can have do something like
(note: you need to sort out the exact syntax, like :foreign_key, and :source, and stuff)

```
class User

  has_many :connections, :foreign_key => "from_user_id"
  has_many :connected_users, :through => :connections, :source => :to_user

  def positive_connections
    connections.where(:value => 1)
  end

  def negative_connections
    ...
  end

end
```

But we also now have a framework to create a complex sql query
(again you need to fill in the blanks... but something like)

```
class User

  def positive_connected_users
    connected_users.joins(:connections).group("from_user_id").having("SUM(connections.value) > 0")
  end

end
```

this isn't quite going to work
but is kind of pseudo code for a real solution

(it might be better to think in pure sql terms)

```
SELECT users.* FROM users
INNER JOIN connections ON to_user_id = users.id
WHERE  from_user_id = #{user.id}
HAVING SUM(connections.value) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew - that was exactly what I was looking for. In fact I've found it simpler in the end to change my models round completely so that users first establish a connection between two other users and then vote on that connection. Not quite as elegant as your solution but it works for my purposes.

Comment: Yeah, I should have suggested you break out a separate model to cash these counts. Else it's going to get slow with any large data set. You may also want to consider Mongo, as it makes it easy to do some of this. Check out https://github.com/vinova/voteable_mongo because you could use similar ideas to this